# typedef with CRTP doesn't work when inheritance is used

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

Is there any ways to define a type with a same name for classes in inheritance relationship by using CTRP? I tried the following code but got `error: member 'ptr_t' found in multiple base classes of different types` from `clang++`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/memory>

template <typename T> class Pointable {
public:
    // define a type `ptr_t` in the class `T` publicly
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> ptr_t;
};

class Parent : public Pointable<Parent> {
public:
    Parent() {
        std::cout << "Parent created" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Parent() {
        std::cout << "Parent deleted" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent,
              public Pointable<Child> {
public:
    Child() {
        std::cout << "Child created" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Child() {
        std::cout << "Child deleted" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Child::ptr_t child_ptr(new Child());
    Parent::ptr_t parent_ptr(new Parent());

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the following one is OK (but it's redundant and go against the DRY principle).

```
class Parent {
public:
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Parent> ptr_t;

    Parent() {
        std::cout << "Parent created" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Parent() {
        std::cout << "Parent deleted" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Child> ptr_t;

    Child() {
        std::cout << "Child created" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Child() {
        std::cout << "Child deleted" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

If there is no ways to achieve this behavior by using CRTP, why that is prohibited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the CRTP, but with multiple inheritance.  `Child` inherits `ptr_t` from both its base classes, and both types are different: `shared_ptr<Parent>` vs. `shared_ptr<Child>`.  Therefore, the compiler cannot figure out which type you mean by `Child::ptr_t` in `main`.

As you pointed out, you have to fix this manually using a `typedef` in `Child` (making your `Pointable` base class useless, though).

```
class Child : public Parent,
              public Pointable<Child> {
public:
    typedef Pointable<Child>::ptr_t ptr_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Child is derived publicly from Parent, there is no way to have the same typedef defined differently in each without putting something inside the definition of Child. However you define the inheritance, Child will inherit the wrong typedef from Parent.

One possibility would be to define a traits class

```
  template<typename T> class Traits
  {
  public:
      typedef std::shared_ptr<T> ptr_t;
  }
```

Obviously in this case that doesn't gain you much, since referring to Traits::ptr_t is longer than Child::ptr_t. (But it might be useful if you have lots of typedefs, or if you want to be able to change the pointer type later.)

Answer (score 0):

If Child is only derivated from Parent (and not explicit from Pointable) it is a `Pointable` to be exact a `Pointabe<Parent>`, cause it isa Parent, and Parent isa Pointable.

A Parent::ptr_t can hold an instance of of Child, cause a Child isa Parent (at least in the sense of the code).

I don't know what you want to do with the ptr_t. You loose the exact type, but you could try to do a `dynamic_cast` up the hierarchy.  Perhaps that is enough.